# MacOS displaying 100s of notifications about 117th birthday

Tags: mail.app

A large number of notifications are being generated for all contacts celebrating a 117th birthday.

There is also no way to bulk dismiss them.

The notifications have a Calendar icon, but this could mean they're from contacts, or another stream such as Facebook etc. Anyone know the cause?

[image]

Comment: I'm seeing the same thing - hundreds of notifications for what looks like random people in my contacts, all saying it's their 117th birthday. My hunch is that it's either a date-related bug in MacOS or perhaps in Facebook (I checked my Accounts, and the only one that's linked to my Calendar is Facebook). 

Not sure why the question has been closed as unclear - it's pretty obvious what the issue is here.

Comment: The initial question didn't contain a question at all, just a rant and a screenshot. The edit helped a lot.